# Play! Framework Eclipse Debug Source Not Found

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, playframework

I have been trying to debug and look through the internals of Play! Frameworks Controller class. If I place break points on the Controller.class, the debugger stops at the break point but throws a "Source Not Found"

I have added play.jar and the project is in path. Even added a Java Classpath called "Play_Home" which points to the Play framework.

**Update**
I been able to always debug my code (your solutions don't help me). When I plan a breakpoint on Play's internal classes like Controller, the debugger stops and says "Source not found"

Comment: In play 1.2 play eclipsify attach the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer is almost a straight copy of my own answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172013/debug-playframework-in-eclipse) that touches the same topic. I assume the problem in your case will be solved by running the `eclipsify` command, as another user has already mentioned.)

---

- Create the configuration files for Eclipse by running `play eclipsify YourProject` command. (See [Play framework documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/ide) for more information.)
- You should now have a folder named `eclipse` in your project. In it, you should see commands `Connect JDPA to YourProject.launch`, `YourProject.launch` and `Test YourProject.launch`.
- Right-click on the `YourProject.launch` and choose `Run As --> YourProject` from the pop-up menu. That will start your application. When the application is running, right-click on the `Connect JDPA to YourProject.launch`, and choose `Debug As --> Connect JDPA to YourProject.launch` from the pop-up menu. That will start a debug session on your application.

Comment: I am able to debug my code. However, when I place a break point in one of Play's classes: the debugger stops at the right break point and says "source not found"

Comment: Is your Play installation complete then? If it is, `eclipsify` command should automatically create correct project settings for Eclipse.

Comment: Yes eclipsify works. I am able to debug and stop at breakpoints in my code. But I want to place breakpoints inside Controller.class and see how templates are getting rendered

Comment: Well, it works for me, and I haven't done any "extra tricks" (in addition to above) to achieve it. Perhaps you should check Java Build Path in your Eclipse - look for the play jar file and see if the source attachment is set correctly. It's pointing at the play/framework directory on my workspace.

Comment: And I wonder what the downvote was for, whoever it was... I think this answer is not that much off.

Comment: Your answer was right. However in addition, I had to re-import the play application into eclipse. Thanks for the help

Comment: This is not relevant to Play 2