# Play Framework 2.1.1: Run/debug configurations

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

I created a play project (version 2.1.1), and I started to develop, using terminal "play run", and now I need to debug my project. But, I don't have any debug/run configurations.
I tried to execute commands like: play eclipse, play debug run, play ~run...But, I can't debug.

How do I debug this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start play in debug mode in a separate command line console:

```
$ play eclipse
$ play debug run
```

which should print...

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9999
```

... and start the app.

Now you can attach a debugger in Eclipse (remote debug attached to port 9999). More details here [Debug Playframework in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172013/debug-playframework-in-eclipse)

Comment: Now it's openning the Debug on eclipse, but it's giving the message "Source not found"